# Bind label to sql database

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a problem with the databinding in wpf, i want to bind a sql record on a label. Normally in window form i use something like this: `Label1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["ColumnName1"].ToString();`
But what about WPF..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You SQL database should fill up your model objects (business logic classes). From there, your WPF view (Xaml file) should be bind to a Controller (View Model if you are in the MVVM pattern) which will be be the bridge between your View and Model in term of binding.

The View will need to bind to the Controller to have access to the data in your model.

```
<Label Content="{Binding MyProperty}">
```

Of course the DataContext will need to be specified before. The DataContext is a way to set the source of your data. It must contain the property you are specifying in the Binding attribute of the Label.

Comment: WPF should be used with MVVM or MVC. Controller is the ViewModel if you want. The source is the DataContext.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, on msdn i have found an interesting article. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx i think this help me a lot :)

Comment: Super, do not forget to mark this answer as Accepted if you are done with your question. Have a nice day.